# dynamically embed new uploaded image/file on website

Tags: google-drive-api

For example, I am embedding the thumbnail and download link of an image that I uploaded to gdrive on my website manually by fetching the image id and adding it to the thumbnail and download placeholder links. Is there any way to automatically detect new image uploads to a folder in google drive and automatically embed the newly uploaded image to my website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think one can only add a notification URL in the [GSuite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579696) managed version -

else one could notify to a [slack channel](https://slack.com/intl/en-de/help/articles/205875058#manage-notifications) and pick up the changes from there.